# Reading a list from a text file and swapping the items

Tags: python

I have a list in a text file in this format. The list has 1000's of entries like this and this is a small sample.

```
myitems =[
      ['some text, A', '12345'],
      ['place name 1', 'AAA'],
      ['some text, A', '12345'],
      ['some text', '12345'],
      ['some text CC', 'wwww'],
      ['new text', '12345'],
      ['other text, A', '12345'],
    ]
```

How do i read the list from the text file and get an output like this.

```
newItems = [
  ['12345', 'some text, A'],
  ['AAA', 'place name 1'],
  ['12345', 'some text, A'],
  ['12345', 'some text'],
  ['wwww', 'some text CC'],
  ['12345', 'new text'],
  ['12345', 'other text, A'],
]
```

I am able to read from the file and manipulate it as a string but how do i get it as a list. Breaking at the comma isn't an option since individual list items might have a comma.

Comment: What do you have in your text file? a `myitems = [...]` or comma-separated lines?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest would be a list comprehension:

```
new_items = [i[::-1] for i in myitems]
```

Comment: just out of curiousity is slice notation faster than reversed .... I guess i could just check...

Answer (score 3):

```
 newItems = [[b, a] for a, b in myitems]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

# Reading your file (the path has been passed in argument) and storing each lines in the array called "input"
input = []
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as all_lines:
    for line in all_lines:
        if line:
            input.append(line)

# Creating your array "newItems"
for j in input: 
    print j

newItems = []
if len(input)>2:
    for i in range(1, len(input)-1):
        # Getting content inside brackets. Ex: {{ 'some text, A', '12345' }}
        my_str = input[i].split("[")[1].split("]")[0]
        my_elements = my_str.split("'")

        # Appending elements
        newItems.append([my_elements[1], my_elements[3]])

print  newItems
```

Comment: This could be what he's asking for

Comment: I would assert my_str.count("[") == 1, same with "]" and check there are 4 " ' " chars

Answer (score 0):

if it really looks like that then

```
 with open(my_file) as f:
   exec(f.read()) #read in the text and evaluate it in python creating myitems variable
   my_list = [reversed(l) for l in myitems]
```

exec is very dangerous and should most likely not be used ... but this should work

better solution

```
 #name yourfile with the myitems = [...] to items.py
 import items
 new_items = [reversed(l) for l in items.myitems]
```

Comment: -1 ``exec()`` is a poor solution with many problems. Use ``ast.literal_eval()``. (Edit: I was writing my comment, patience).

Comment: I changed my answer to something less toxic :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
newItems = []
for line in f:
    foo = re.search("\'(.*)\'.*\'(.*)\'", line) #we assume the values are 
                                                #in single quotes
    if foo is not None:
        a, b = foo.groups()
        newItems.append([b, a])
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the file, use CSV since you state 'the individual items might have commas'

Example:

if your file actually looks like this:

```
'some text, A','12345'
'place name 1','AAA'
'some text, A','12345' 
'some text','12345'
'some text CC','wwww' 
'new text','12345'
'other text, A','12345'
```

Then this code reads the csv file and reverses the fields:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv','rb') as csvIN:
    for row in csv.reader(csvIN, delimiter=',',quotechar="'"):
        print row
        row=row[::-1]
        print '==>',row,'\n'
```

Prints:

```
['some text, A', '12345']
==> ['12345', 'some text, A'] 

['place name 1', 'AAA']
==> ['AAA', 'place name 1'] 

['some text, A', '12345 ']
==> ['12345 ', 'some text, A'] 

['some text', '12345']
==> ['12345', 'some text'] 

['some text CC', 'wwww ']
==> ['wwww ', 'some text CC'] 

['new text', '12345']
==> ['12345', 'new text'] 

['other text, A', '12345']
==> ['12345', 'other text, A']
```